# Is nslookup only using the primary DNS Server?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, dns

I added a Pihole recently to my system and managed to get the primary DNS the pihole as well as secondary DNS google and others.

If I shut down pihole I can still browse, because the other DNS servers are queried.

If I use "nslookup www.google.de" I get a response from pihole, if it is up.
I do not get a response, if pihole is down, but I can browse the web.

Question:
Is nslookup only using the primary DNS server and not the others given?
Is this normal then, that when pihole is down I can browsde but nslookup does not resolve?

Comment: What OS are you asking about? There are several different programs all called "nslookup" -- are you talking about the one that comes with Windows, or the one that comes with Bind9 on Linux/BSD?

Comment: Sorry, Windows 8.1, stock nslookup